# apache jmeter does not show my data in the browser (I use FireFox as a browser)

Tags: jmeter

**i am testing using jmeter, but my data does not arrive when I start the browser with http test script recorder. i can't do operations such as insert update either**

Answer (score 1):

If JMeter doesn't work as you expect in the majority of cases the answer is in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging). It's also a good idea to check your [browser console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) and look for any suspicious entries of WARN and/or ERROR severity.

In the majority of cases problems with recording are connected with [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) and JMeter's self-signed certificate installation, see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of JMeter User Manual on the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for more details.

Also be aware that it's possible to use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) for recording your browser actions into JMeter .jmx script, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.